# Establecer Zona horaria JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy intentando sacar la hora en la zona horaria de Europa (Madrid) y no lo consigo, esto viendo la API de JAVA, y no se si usar la clase SimpleDateFormat.

Una cosa así, pero claro yo quiero establecer la zona horaria UTC para la hora

```
SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = isoFormat.parse("2010-05-23T09:01:02");
```

Answer (score 0):

te dejo un ejemplo de como lo puedes hacer.

```
// Java 7
        {
            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            calendar.set(2015, 0, 31, 12, 0, 0);

            SimpleDateFormat sdfMadrid = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
            sdfMadrid.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Madrid"));
        }

// Java 8
        {
            ZonedDateTime fecha = ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 1, 31, 12, 00, 00, 00, ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid"));

            System.out.println("\nJava 8");
            System.out.printf("Hora Madrid:\t\t %s\n", fecha);

        }
```

Comment: Lo que he hecho es coger la hora y restar uno, porque lo que me hace es que si son las 8 me pone las 9.

Así:

    String guardarHora = horaPedido + "";
    System.out.println(guardarHora);
    String[] sacarhora = guardarHora.split(":");
    String horaES = sacarhora[0];
    int quitaruno = Integer.parseInt(horaES)-1;
    String unirxD = quitaruno + ":" + sacarhora[1] + ":" + sacarhora[2];
    System.out.println(unirxD);

Answer (score 0):

```
            String guardarHora = horaPedido + "";
            System.out.println(guardarHora);
            String[] sacarhora = guardarHora.split(":");
            String horaES = sacarhora[0];
            int quitaruno = Integer.parseInt(horaES)-1;
            String unirxD = quitaruno + ":" + sacarhora[1] + ":" + sacarhora[2];
            System.out.println(unirxD);
```